# Accessing a folder inside rootPath - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written some code in Javascript to get data out of a json file. When the test.json is in the **root** of the project it works, but now the json file is in a folder that is inside the root.

**/root/someFolder/test.json**

is there any way that I can redirect the path inside the folder?
(Since there are more json files I can't have them all in the root)

```
function getConfiguredData(keyName) {
        let data = undefined;
        let folderPath = vscode.workspace.rootPath;
        if (folderPath) {
            console.log(`folderPath: ${folderPath}`);
            if (fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
                data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(folderPath, 'test.json'), 'utf8'))[keyName];
            }}
```

Comment: Just build the correct path? `path.join(folderPath, 'someFolder', 'test.json')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node's [`path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) accepts as many arguments as you need! 
You can see this in the documentation by the argument's notation of `[...paths]`, and it's even explained in more detail:

> `...paths <string>` A sequence of path segments

The provided example code makes it quite clear what you can achieve with this method:

```js
path.join('/foo', 'bar', 'baz/asdf', 'quux', '..');
// Returns: '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
```

So in your case, you can build the path to your file like this:

```js
path.join(folderPath, 'someFolder', 'test.json');
```